# How to add a new google map view(the new with api v2 for android) as a item into a listview?

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

I am using a mapview in listview,it's a part of item view in the listview,now i need to change the api  v1 to v2,but i can not,because the new api only support the GoogleMap view with a frgment,i don't know how to implements that,it always say "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment".It's anyone here can help?Thank you very much! 
the key code what i use is same with blew:
in layout,i add the follow code to a LinearLayout:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

android:layout_height="match_parent" />

and in the java code,i try to get the GoogleMap view in this way(in the getView method of my own adapter with extends the BaseAdapter),here is the code:

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you recieve derived from the fact that you are trying to get a `MapFragment` object as it's specified in your XML file using the `SupportFragmentManager` object.

Instead use the `FragmentMananger` object to get the `MapFragment`, like so:

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Of course this depends on what is you target API you develop you application to. if your taget api > 11 then use the following line and a simple `Activity` class. in other case change you XML object of the map to `SupportMapFragment` and use the line you have used:

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

in this case you `Acitivity` should extend an `FragmentActivity` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help,i am so stupid.now i got a new problem,i can not hide that fragment!!!

Comment: please open a new question and provide you current code in it and I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

`

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`

and java code like this

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and make sure your class extends FragmentActivity